# Atiyah flop, flip and related toric computation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, birational-geometry

I am trying to understand the definitions of flips and flops by studying 
examples in [this](http://www.math.utah.edu/~hacon/FlipsFlops.pdf) article of Hacon and McKernan. I would like to ask why the toric varieties constructed in Ex. 1.13 are indeed flips and flops. It is possible that my question can be solved simply answering  **how to compute relative canonical divisor of a toric morphism**.

As far as I know (please correct me if I am wrong), a *flip* $X_{-}\dashrightarrow X_{+}$ between termnal, $\mathbb Q$-factorial varieties is a birational map which is an isomorphism in codimension one and factors as $\varphi_{+}^{-1}\circ \varphi_{-}$, where:

- $\varphi_{-}\colon X_{-}\to X$ is a small extremal contraction,
- $\varphi_{+}\colon X_{+}\to X$ is a small contraction such that
  $K_{X_{+}}$ is relatively ample.

A *flop* is defined in the same way, but the above two conditions are replaced by:

- $\varphi_{-}$, $\varphi_{+}$ are small contractions such that $K_{X_{+}}$ and $K_{X_{-}}$ are relatively trivial.

The variety $X$ above is only required to be normal.

The well known Atiyah flop is constructed as follows: let $X$ be a cone over a quadric surface, $\tilde{X}\to X$ be a blowup of its vertex, and $X_{+}$ and $X_{-}$ are given by contracting one of the two rulings of the exceptional divisor inside $\tilde{X}$. My first question is: is it immediate to see that $K_{X_{-}}$ and $K_{X_{+}}$ are relatively trivial in this case?

In the cited paper, Atiyah flop is given a following toric description: let $v_{1},v_{2},v_3,v_4\in \mathbb R^{3}$ be four vectors such that any three of them span the standard lattice $\mathbb Z^{3}$ and
$$\tag{$*$} v_{1}+v_{3}=v_{2}+v_{4}.$$
These vectors generate a full-dimensional cone. Now the fan of $X_{-}$ is constructed from this cone by adding a wall joining $v_{1}$ with $v_{3}$, and the fan of $X_{+}$ is constructed by adding a wall between $v_{2}$ with $v_{4}$ (adding both these walls is the same as adding a ray $v_{1}+v_{3}$, which gives $\tilde{X}$). Now again, my question is, how to use this description to compute the relative canonical divisors and show that $X_{-}\dashrightarrow X_{+}$ is a flop?

Next, the authors say that one can obtain an example of a *flip* by replacing $(*)$ with, say,
$$\tag{$**$} 2v_{1}+v_{3}=v_{2}+v_{4},$$
and follow the same construction. Now $X_{-}$ is singular, $X_{+}$ is smooth. My question is, again, **how to see that this is a flip**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following criterion is useful to determine whether a toric-invariant extremal ray is positive/negative/trivial without computing the exact intersection number (cf. Proposition 4.3, *Decomposition of toric morphisms* by Miles Reid):

> (1) Let $F$ be a fan, and $X=X_{F}$; then $K_X$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor if and only if the roof of $F$ is flat over every $\sigma \in F$; that is, for all $\sigma=\langle e_{1},\dots,e_{s}\rangle\in F^{(k)}$, $\left[e_{1},\dots,e_{s} \right]$ is a polyhedron contained in a $(k-1)$-dimensional affine subspace of $N_{\mathbb{R}}$.

> (2) Suppose that $K_{X}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier, and let $w \in F^{(n-1)}$ be an interior wall. Then $K_{X}\cdot l_{w} < 0$ (resp. $=0$, $>0)$ if and only if $\mathrm{shed}\ F$ is strictly convex (resp. flat, strictly concave) in a small neighbourhood of a point $P \in (\mathrm{int}\ w) \cap \mathrm{roof}\ F$.

Roughly speaking, you can look at the polytope created by the origin and the primitive generators of the cones. In Atiyah's flop, the $4$ generators lie on the same plane, so the walls are flat and hence rays are trivial. In the second example, the wall of $v_1$ and $v_{3}$ is concave and the wall of $v_{2}$ and $v_{4}$ is convex. Hence if you remove the wall of $v_{2}$ and $v_{4}$ and replace it by the wall of $v_1$ and $v_{3}$, you get a flip.

If you do a little more work, you can compute the exact intersection number by the Cartier data of $K_{X}$, see section 6.3 and 6.4 of the book *Toric Varieties* by David Cox, John Little and Hal Schenck.